Shell script error while using "=" in regular expression
Why does the below script fail if i add "=" in the first and second character class of the regular expression.
#! /bin/bash

read -p "Enter an email address: " email

if [[ $email =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%=-+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.=-+]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ ]]
then
   echo "Valid mail id "
else
   echo "invalid mail id"
fi

It works fine when i remove "=", does it hold any special meaning.

works fine for what input? Can you hardcode and post an exapmle? Please post example execution of the script when it "fails". Why does the below script fail if Does the script really fail, if so, what is the error mesage? Or does the script sucseed and prints the message invalid mail id?

The = is not the problem, the dash - is.
The dash has a special meaning in a character class: it introduces a range. Place it first or last in the class to make it match the literal dash:
if [[ $email =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%=+-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9.=+-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ ]]
#                               ~                 ~       

For example:
while read char; do
    [[ $char =~ [+-=] ]] && echo "$char matches"
done < <(perl -le 'print join "\n", map chr, 32 .. 126')

returns
+ matches
, matches
- matches
. matches
/ matches
: matches
; matches
< matches
= matches

while using [=-+] makes it return nothing.

A couple tips aside the character class issue explained by @choroba:
Sometimes wrapping regex testing in a function gives code clarity, especially when reading it months/years later or by someone-else.
Also here, bash dialect is not really needed (if you think of it, it is often not needed at all but a shell compatibility problem).
#!/usr/bin/env sh

isValidMail(){
  printf %s "$1" | grep -qE '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%=+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.=+-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
}

printf 'Enter an email address: ' 
read -r email

if isValidMail "$email"
then
   echo "Valid mail id"
else
   echo "invalid mail id"
fi


Spawning a subprocess is a lot of performance hit to avoid a portability issue.

@CharlesDuffy it trades performance for peace of mind. Given the shell context it is a good deal.
